# Add ClientId to the "Authorized API Clients"

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

I have web app, which requires users to authenticate using google's oauth2. Assuming that the user is admin in his organization and that I have his access token at hand, how can I add ServiceAccount's ClientId to the *Authorized API Clients* list in the admin console **programmatically**?

I'm doing this with .NET 4.6.1, but any solution would be helpful.

It should be added here: [Print screen of the Google Admin's Manage API client access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9b55.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You cant that there is no api to fill in that information.

Comment: Too bad, I also failed to find a way to access organization users' gdrive/gmail data using admin token. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DalmTo has pointed out there is no api for this currently.